# When does this iterated logarithm series converge / diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

**Question:** Let $b > 1$ be a positive real, let $\ell_b(n) = \max(1, \lfloor \log_b n \rfloor)$, and let $f_b(n) = n \ell_b(n) \ell_b^2(n) \dots $ (where we iterate $\ell_b$ until we hit $1$). For what values of $b$ does the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f_b(n)}$$

converge or diverge?

[This previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780795/infinite-series-over-recursive-digit-counts/4780901) asks about the case $b = 10$. There I gave an argument which shows that the series diverges for all $b > e$. I thought I had convinced myself awhile ago that this series ought to diverge for all $b > 1$ but surprisingly the argument does not show it; actually it suggests that the series converges for $b < e$ and it's unclear what happens if $b = e$.

My motivation is the same as Alan's in the linked question: this is an interesting test of the limits of common convergence tests. The integral test or [Cauchy condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) shows that the analogue of this series where we only iterate $\ell_b(n)$ a fixed number of times diverges for any $b > 1$ but that argument doesn't work here. Actually Cauchy condensation produces nearly the same series again, which is basically the idea I use in my argument in the linked question.

Comment: Similar problem https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111244/series-with-iterated-logs-does-it-converge .

Comment: @Erik: thanks! So looks like it diverges when $b = e$. I think we can show that using a refinement of the estimates in the linked question, which maybe should even show that it converges when $b < e$ but I haven't checked the details.